# angularjs expression should we only check for value or both value and type (=== or ==)

Tags: angularjs

When using angularjs directive and expression should we use value and type checking operator or just value checking. which one is correct out of following.

```
ng-show="count === 1"
```

or

```
 ng-show="count == 1"
```

Comment: What you're asking is if you want coercion or not. This is up to you, although I always go with the identity comparison as it forces both type and value equality (I handle type casts on my own for sanity). The current best practice also seems to be stick with identity and skip equality.

Comment: If you do `'1' == 1` then it will be false for 1st case where as true for `2nd` case, so 1st would be more convenient

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If you're using angular2 with [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), you can reliably use the strict equality operator (`===`) since you shouldn't need to do type coercion in the *template*: your component or service should discover that something is passing along a `'5'` where it expected a `5`.

If you're still on angular 1, I'd say it largely depends on the consequences of an invalid coercion and how much control you have over the inputs to your application.

If you're requesting JSON from a REST service you control and your front-end expects a value to be a `number`, send it a `number` and use `===`.

If you're consuming some third-party API and you can't be sure what it's sending, check and either recast or equality-check accordingly. But in this case that the API breaks its contract and sends `null` or boolean `false` in the place of that `number` you were hoping for, you probably want to [be defensive](http://scottdorman.github.io/2008/07/04/what-is-ldquodefensive-programmingrdquo/) and react accordingly before it hits your template anyway.

I'm personally a fan of always using `===` and designing the application to type-check and recast where it makes sense, but that is largely an opinion.

Counter-anecdote to the above: at a previous job we transitioned from one database engine to another. All the relationships built in our front-end used identity comparisons. The new database driver decided to return a `string` instead of a `number` for record IDs, but not for relationship mappings. It took us a while to refactor for that. What benefit did having the identity comparison bring us in the first place? I'd argue none. If we had used equality comparison (`==`) it would have worked virtually out of the box and not been at a greater risk for breaking.